# Seeds.rb development environment also getting applied to test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I need certain things to be seeded into a test environment, specifically, user roles from CanCan. BUT it seems to load everything under development.

*lib/tasks/test* _ *seed.rake*

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :test do
    task :prepare => :environment do
      Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

which correctly pulls in seeds.rb after running bundle exec rake db:test:prepare

*db/seeds.rb*

```
admin = Role.create( { name: "admin" }, :without_protection => true)
user  = Role.create( { name: "user"  }, :without_protection => true)

if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?

  admin = User.create!({ name:     "Admin",
                         email:    "admin@example.com",
                         password: "foobar",
                         password_confirmation: "foobar",
                         role_ids:  1 },
                         :without_protection => true)
  admin.confirm!    

  if Rails.env.development?

    48.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@example.com"
      password  = "foobar"
      fake = User.create!({ name:     name,
                            email:    email,
                            password: password,
                            password_confirmation: password },
                            :without_protection => true)
      fake.confirm!
    end
  end
end
```

All looks good but then........

```
$ rails console test
Loading test environment (Rails 3.2.8)
  > User.first
User Load (1.0ms) SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  => #<User id: 1, email: "admin@example.com" ..................
  > Rails.env.development?
  => false
```

What wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the environment variable `ENV` to `test` before launching task.

Comment: im not sure what you mean. the namespace targets db:test:prepare and it should be controlled in seeds.rb

Comment: This is likely the right answer because Rails defaults to the development environment, then at some point switches to the test environment as part of running the test task. It is not necessarily the case that it would switch Rails.env to test before executing db:test:prepare. From Rails' perspective, all it needs to do is switch the env before starting the test suite. IMO, you should keep seeds for dev/prod, and leave test setup to the test suite itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing:

`$ RAILS_ENV=test rake db:seed`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you are using the same database for development and test environments. Check your database.yml

Comment: no, databases are being used correctly. would be a problem though because then everytime i run tests the dev database would be cleared, haha

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to execute it in your terminal:
`echo $RAILS_ENV`

- If it is showing `test` then you have your answer.
- If is not, verify your `config/database.yml` to see if it is using the same database for both environments.

Verify also your `config/environment.rb`